# How to apply the definition of limit points to $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\textbf{Definition}$: A point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $S$ if every deleted neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$. We denote the set of all limit points by $L(S)$.

I am struggling to apply the definition given. Consider these examples and my reasoning.

> Example 1. $L(\mathbb{N})=\emptyset$.

From the definition, it seems that one can take an arbitrary deleted neighbourhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Why cannot one make every deleted neighbourhood arbitrary large such that it contains a point in $\mathbb{N}$? Will not this satisfy the definition? Where is my understanding of the definition flawed here?

> Example 2. $L(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$.

It's likely that my reasoning is erroneous for why this is, as I cannot even grasp the first example. How should one think about this example intuitively? I am familiar with the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Notice the **every** in "every deleted neighbourhood".

Comment: In $\mathbb N$ (seen as a metric space), every deleted neighborhood of radius $<1$ is empty. You should be familiar with the "sparsity" of $\mathbb N$ in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example 1. $L(\mathbb{N}) = \emptyset$

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It's true, arbitrary large neighborhoods $n$ are amongst those you have to consider. But you can't confine attention to *only* large neighborhoods of $n$: you also have to contend with $U = (n - \frac 1 2, n + \frac 1 2)$, and clearly $(U \setminus \!\{n\}) \cap \mathbb{N} = \emptyset$. It's the small neighborhoods that matter.

> Example 2. $L(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ every deleted neighborhood of $x$ contains a rational, so $x$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$.